# Possible side effects changing "normal" code with anonymous function

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, side-effects

I must change some code in a big legacy application. Some portions of code must be replaced with a call inside an anonymous function. How sure can I be that I will not suffer side effects?

The change is more or less this

```cs
lines of legacy code...
lines of legacy code...
lines of legacy code...
```

with

```cs
void Execute(Action a) => a();

lines of legacy code...

Execute( () => 
{
 lines of legacy code...
 lines of legacy code...
});

lines of legacy code...
```

The function executes the `Action` as soon as is called.

If anyone wants more details: I am applying the `SqlAzureExecutionStrategy` policy in a legacy app. But it does not support transactions. So for every transaction I must cancel the policy.

MS Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-resiliency/retry-logic

Example pseudo code:
Original

```cs
lines of legacy code...
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
 lines of legacy code...
 ts.Complete();
}

lines of legacy code...
```

replace with:

```cs
lines of legacy code...
var executionStrategy = new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(0, 0); //No retry

executionStrategy.Execute( () =>
{
 using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
 {
  lines of legacy code...
  ts.Complete();
 }
});
lines of legacy code...
```

Could I safely make the changes taking in consideration that there is a lot of legacy code?

Comment: Why do this? It seems like it doesn't change the code at all except make it more complicated. What are you hoping to acheive?

Comment: I want to use the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy. This would apply a retry policy to the whole DDBB access code, but some sections (the ones that uses transactions) it is not compatible so must be disabled.

The most of the code does not use transaction so the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy will be useful.